# SMS Text Message Integration with Salesforce NPSP

Tags: workflow, appexchange, npsp

I am working with a budget constrained non profit who would like to add outbound text messaging alerts to their NPSP based application. This seems relatively uncomplicated but there are several apps that provide this capability for a monthly fee + data charges. Can this be done using the cell provider text messaging email address or do I need a messaging service ?

Comment: I used to SMS Magic's https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000024XvyEAE solution, and I will recommend them to your need. And it's more cost-efficient and integrated with Salesforce. You can send custom message all in clickable setup.

Comment: I've heard from folks that Twilio might be building a managed solution so might be worth checking with them to see if that is still happening...

Answer (score 2):

You can try 360 SMS App that allows users to add outbound text messaging alerts to their application. It’s effective and inexpensive. Moreover, if you register now and use coupon code JUNE16, you can use the app absolutely free for the first year. To know more, you can visit: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpSyIEAV

Mention that you are Not for Profit and they will give you additional amazing Discounts.